# jquery button class changing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a button with a class attached to it which relates to one of 2 functions, when I click the page I want the class of the button to change to the second jQuery function.

Currently the setup is as follows:

```
<button id="btn" class="func1">click</button>
```

When I click on the button I want `func2` to load instead of `func1`

Sorry for the naivety.

Answer (score 0):

check out 
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass( "func1 func2" )
 })
```